# Meta-analysis: Difference between direct and indirect restriction of range

Tags: meta-analysis, bias

Looking at meta-analysis for personnel selection procedures, I am having really big troubles to figure out the difference between concepts of direct restriction of range (DRR) and indirect restriction of range (IRR).

Can someone help me out with an easy explaination and an example for DRR and IRR?

Comment: I'm not domain knowledgeable, but found [this article](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Huy_Le5/publication/7046251_Implications_of_direct_and_indirect_range_restriction_for_meta-analysis_methods_and_findings/links/00463513f597fe7e82000000.pdf) which opens with what seems like a pretty clear example.